# Create conditional sum score in new column R

Tags: r, dplyr

EDIT: I added another column with `day` in the sample data, as `beep` is nested within `day`.

I have the following data. I am trying to get a sum of `a` in the row of `beep = 3` by, `beep`, `day`, and `id`. See column `b` for what I would like to achieve. I have tried it using `dyplr` and `group_by`, but so far no succes. Any ideas on how to approach this are much appreciated!

Note: actual data contains missings in `beep` (skipped)

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), date = c("1-1-2022", "1-1-2022", "1-1-2022", "2-1-2022", 
"2-1-2022", "2-1-2022", "1-1-2022", "1-1-2022", "1-1-2022", "2-1-2022", 
"2-1-2022", "2-1-2022"), beep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), a = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), b = c(NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

| id | day | beep | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-22 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 1 | 1-1-22 | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 1-1-22 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2-1-22 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 1 | 2-1-22 | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 2-1-22 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1-1-22 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 1-1-22 | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 1-1-22 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2-1-22 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 2-1-22 | 2 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 2-1-22 | 3 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: I am sorry, could you please explain in further details what operation is behind `b`?

Comment: Column `b` is the sum of `a` grouped by `day` and `id`. I would need the sum score in the row of `beep` = 3.

Comment: So, you want the `cumsum()` for all the rows within `id` and `day` up to `beep == 3`. That is, if you have `beep = 4` you would not consider that.

Comment: Yes, but in this df`beep = 4` doesn't exist,  but there may be cases where `beep == 3` is misssing, and where then I wouldn't need the sum either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ave` which will populate the summary statistic (in this case `sum`) across *all* rows for each unique group, defined here by both `df$date` and `df$id`:

```
df$ave_b <- ave(df$a, df$date, df$id, FUN = sum)
```

If you then want to only keep the sum in those rows where `beep = 3`, you can set the rest to `NA`

```
is.na(df$ave_b) <- !df$beep == 3
```

The resulting column will be filled with `NA` for all other values of `beep`

```
> df
   id     date beep a  b ave_b
1   1 1-1-2022    1 1 NA    NA
2   1 1-1-2022    2 0 NA    NA
3   1 1-1-2022    3 1  2     2
4   1 2-1-2022    1 1 NA    NA
5   1 2-1-2022    2 0 NA    NA
6   1 2-1-2022    3 0  1     1
7   2 1-1-2022    1 1 NA    NA
8   2 1-1-2022    2 0 NA    NA
9   2 1-1-2022    3 0  1     1
10  2 2-1-2022    1 1 NA    NA
11  2 2-1-2022    2 1 NA    NA
12  2 2-1-2022    3 0  2     2
```

There's a one-liner using `tapply` but it will fail if there are groups with no `beep == 3` - this is the safest technique I can think of.

Disclaimer: if you have cases where `beep > 3`, as per Francesco Grossetti's comment, those would be summed too - is this possible, and if so what is your desired behaviour?

Comment: Thank you so much. This two-step approach worked for me. I did add in a custom function to deal with NAs in `a` that would otherwise be ignored.

`df$ave_b <- ave(df$a, df$date, df$id, FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm=T)`